# Drupal 7 Javascript does not store values

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I am getting data through Ajax call. That data has following code that stores some value from PHP to Javascript variables using .data(). I am pretty sure php variable has valuesbut values does not get stored in js. Take a look

So there is ajax method

```
'#ajax' => array(
                    'callback' => 'a_e_get_score',
```

It calls the function that has js code

```
$out .= '
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#chkso").data("paragraphs",' . json_encode($this->result->data->analysis->so->paragraphs) . ');
jQuery("#chkso").data("domExpression",' . json_encode($this->result->data->analysis->so->paragraphDOM) . ');
jQuery("#chkso").data("tooSimpleColor",' . json_encode($light_blue) . ');
jQuery("#chkso").data("tooComplexColor",' . json_encode($light_orange) . ');
</script>';
      return $out;
```

Now when I try to run

```
$("#chkso").data('paragraphs');
```

it says undefined.

How do I really pass these values ? I know there is another way mentioned [here](https://drupal.org/node/756722) but that does not seems to work for me as well.

Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all for the help. [drupal_json_encode](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_encode/7) did the trick for me. Following code works with no problem.

```
 $out .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                         var tooSimpleColor = ' . drupal_json_encode($light_blue) . ';
                         var tooComplexColor = ' . drupal_json_encode($light_orange) . ';
                         var domExpression = ' . drupal_json_encode($this->result->data->analysis->so->paragraphDOM) . ';
                         var paragraphs = ' . drupal_json_encode($this->result->data->analysis->so->paragraphs) . ';
                         </script>';
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you use the drupal_add_js() function.

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');
```

then in your javascript file you can access your value like this:

```
Drupal.settings.myModule.key
```

If you want to send data to javascript from your module file only, you don't need to use this

```
'#ajax' => array(
                 'callback' => 'a_e_get_score',
```

Comment: this looks right, but for some unknown reasons (to me) it did not really work. I however found another way to get this working. I am gonna post that answer soon.